# varchar(25000) or text. What's the proper data type for this variable data?

Tags: mysql

I have this table, which contains a column, which can store strings of different sizes, these can be simple words like "hello" or long texts of up to 25 thousand characters.

I know the byte sizes of the data types and I have read some answers from this same site, but I have not found concrete references that allow me to decide on this particular case.

25000 maximum data is too much for varchar?

Maybe yes, then I should use text. But what if most of the strings do not exceed 20 characters and there are only a few exceptions where the text is 25000 characters long?

What type of data should I use? Varchar (25000) or text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not building something with has to take care of every little byte of space on your DB-server I guess it doesn't really matter. If you have a large amout of records below 255 bytes, you'll save about one byte for each record if going for `varchar`.

In cases like this I personally prefer `text`, mainly because avoiding running into trouble with a too small defined length.

From the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings):

> Data Type: `VARCHAR(M)`, `VARBINARY(M)`
>   Storage Required: L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 − 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require
>   more than 255 bytes
>
> Data Type: `BLOB`, `TEXT`
>   Storage Required: L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16

Comment: Ok, the records are just 150, so with varchar I'll save 150 bytes at most. But what's that trouble you're avoiding? I didn't get it.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo A fictional example: some devs try hard to estimate the possible length of text values (p.e. an address is max. 500 bytes => varchar(500)). Then for whatever reasons the address has to be expanded, that means you have to adjust the table definition. Since I've had this in the past, I avoid running into this issue by using `text` if it ain't described otherwise.